# How can I connect to Mysql of my of my local from the EC2 ubuntu system?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, database-connection, aws-security-group

I am having mysql server in my premise which is running on windows. Now I want connect this mysql database from an ubuntu ec2 instance but it is giving can't connect to mysql server at my IP (110 connection error)

[image]

Can some one help me to connect from ubuntu to my local window.

For  your info: I am not able even ping from ubuntu instance to my local IP

Comment: Have you turned off the firewall? if it is on your connection will be blocked by firewall

Comment: Firewall settings are off.

Comment: Is there any work around??

Answer (score 0):

Add MySQL IP on EC2 security group and port will be 3306 
then 
Use the below command to install the MySQL client on your ec2 instance.
sudo apt install mysql-* -y

after installation of mysql on ubuntu try to connect with the MYSQL using below command.
mysql -h hostname -u username -p password -P Portno

Hope so this will help you.

Comment: No, still I am getting the same error message as can;t connect to mysql server on my IP(110 conncection timed out).

Comment: Is there any changes should be done in my local system where I am running MySQL?

Comment: Not able to ping to my local system from ec2 ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

In able to connect to an MySQL server exists in EC2 instance you should provide some main parameters like:

> - Connection Method: Standard TCP/IP over SSH
> - SSH Hostname: the public ipv4 address of your EC2 Ubuntu instance
> - SSH Username: ubuntu
> - SSH Key File: your AWS credentials (key pair) file

And enable rules for connecting to MySQL server in your SecurityGroup:

> (TCP on port 3306).

and you should be able to connect smoothly.

And for more information refer to this link:
[reference](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-mysql-workbench-connect-your-server-aws-ec2-ubuntu-william-ku/)

Comment: I am connecting to My laptop from EC2 not visa versa